# Manipulating and accessing char *s pointer variable (string) using another pointer variable char *c - C

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

I've hit a roadblock, when trying to manipulate strings when "storing" them as pointer variables.

```
// Sample code to input a string till line break is encountered, later re-allocating to save space
char *s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
scanf("%[^\n]", s);
s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);

// Code to replace whitespaces with newlines
for (char *c = s; *c != '\0'; c++) {
    if (*c == ' ') {
        *c = '\n';
    }
}

printf("%s", s);
```

I want an explanation of `char *c = s` in the above code snippet, because when I tried to use the same concept to iterate over the string characters in *another example* (below) I was greeted with Segmentation fault runtime error.

I want to find the frequency of digits (0 to 9) from a string entered by the user:

```
int count[10];
char *s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
scanf("%[^\n]", &s);
s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);

for(char *c = s; *c != '\0'; c++) {  // Shows Segementation fault here
    if(*c >= '0' && *c <= '9') {
        count[*c - '0'] += 1;  // I am still trying to work this
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, don't show us *working* code, show the one which is *not working*.

Comment: Edited as requested.

Comment: Well, your `count` is uninitialized. This is one problem. The other is already answered down there...

Comment: Why `malloc` followed by `realloc` ? And by the way `s = realloc(s, ...)` is an anti-pattern. If `realloc` fails you lose your original pointer and leak memory.

Comment: @John3136 I would say it's an attempt to save memory by shrinking it to only what is needed.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Misguided and overcomplicates what should be simple code. If I was the tutor OP would lose points. The whole concept is wrong - allocate way more than I think I need (but no guarantee it is enough), then shrink it to what I need? (with the risk of failure, leakage and no error check?). If the `realloc` was done properly and error checked I'd be less worked up about it ;-). Last point - we all know that the footprint wont get smaller when you reduce the allocation right? It just increases the free pool.

Comment: Thankyou all! My queries are solved. I understood the cause (and reason) of segmentation fault, count needed to be initialised like `count[10] = {0, }` (or is there  a better way?), and that my core logic was correct. Also +Eugene is correct as to why I've `realloc`, although I wonder if there is a better way to handle similar tasks.

Comment: @John3136 I'm very much interested in knowing a more optimised way of doing this, keeping in mind I don't know the length of input string.

Comment: @swingcake It depends on the context: Perhaps there is an upper bound (like line length). Perhaps you can use some sort of stream to increase memory as you go. Perhaps you can limit the input to match your self imposed max (which you should do anyway to avoid overflows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

explanation of `char *c = s`:

in this statement, the pointer c is set to the same address as the pointer s for the first iteration of the for-loop. That means, c and s point to the same memory location. Then, for each further iteration of the for-loop, c is incremented (c++) and the for loop is executed as long as the dereferenced memory location (the content at the memory location) is not the null character.

Now for the segmentation fault, as you didn't post the non-working code, I can only guess. One guess could be that there is no null character inside the allocated memory, so the for loop is not stopping soon enough and increments the c pointer to an address higher than allocated with malloc. By dereferencing it you access a memory location outside the allocated memory. This can produce a segmentation fault.

Edit:
ah, now I see you added the non-working code. Yes, Akshay's answer is right and the segmentation fault could already happen there, as you don't scanf to s but to the memory location where the pointer variable is saved. The array pointed by s is still uninitialized (unknown values) but you search for the first occurence of the null character with strlen. Now, realloc may fail and thus return NULL and then you would set your c pointer to NULL. That would also produce a segmentation fault.

Comment: Great explanation, precisely what I wanted to know and understand.

Answer (score 1):

In **scanf** you are using **&s** instead of **s**.